# Leightweight Window Toolkit

Tags: c++, user-interface

I'm searching for a leightweight window toolkit.

1. It should be

   - leightweight
   - not overloaded with features like Qt
   - **cross platform (Windows, Linux, if possible MAC)**
   - open source
2. Requirements

   - **Basic controls**

     - Buttons
     - Lists
     - Checkboxes
     - Dialogues
     - Progress Bars
     - nothing special
   - **Support for Vulkan**

     - It must support embedding Vulkan. It will be used to show Mesh Data for a Boundary Element Method Solver and display the results
   - **C++ Interface**

The only one that looked ok I found was EFL.

Comment: Why does EFL not work for you, then?

Comment: EFLs Support for Windows seems incomplete und experimental